# What was the first algorithm to be branded as NP Complete?

Tags: algorithm, np

There should have been an initial problem to start building the set of NPC problems. Only then could problems be added to the set NPC , from the set NP by showing that the problem in NP is reducible to that first problem in NPC. So, what was the first problem to be added to NPC and how did someone conclude that it was indeed NPC.

(Note: Google searched, No answers. I'm hoping that someone's professor here had mentioned something like this in class )

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_levin_theorem

Answer (score 2):

It was a satisfiability or SAT problem.

History:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Proof:
http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/CNF_SAT_is_NP-complete